# Send Return Value directly to Channel

Tags: go, return-value, channel

Is it possible to send a function's return value directly to a golang channel? The below doesn't work:

```
BytesOutChan<-, err = bufio.NewWriter(conn).Write(...)
```

Is there any way to do this? Failing that, is there any way to automatically add to a variable? For example, in C you can do this:

```
myInt += fReturnsInt();
```

You can do this golang, but is it possible with multiple return values? This would cut down the verbosity of my code greatly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Go language currently provides no special syntax to do what you want.

Comment: Damn, I wish they did. Right now I have to do the very verbose procedure of storing the return value, adding it up, sending it a channel. Oh well. I'll make a suggestion on the mailing list.

Comment: @JesseBrands How would that even work, though? In the case there are no errors, it's fine, in other cases, the other return items could be garbage, so what should happen to that assignment? They don't necessarily half to be zero-values. If you don't ever care about the errors and can handle any value being returned, maybe just provide some wrappers?

Comment: @JasonCoco That's something I realised later as well. I figured on an error, the function would return a 0 value anyway.